# How to change layout autocomplete dropdown list in Opencart

Tags: php, jquery, autocomplete, opencart

When we used autocomplete in opencart admin then it shows a drop down list of product names (just Like a featured products modules). I want to show model number instead of product name. if anyone know how i can do it ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check the console of what file is being called when you `keyup` on your input. You should be able to go to that file, and modify what you need

Comment: its go on http://localhost/oc/admin/index.php?route=catalog/product/autocomplete&token=bbab19658f5d2ca1987930c5537ef93b&filter_name=i  buti want to modify response layout .. want to show model number instead of name in this list

Comment: Just show the model, or search models instead?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to show instead on product name show model name or some other thing.
go to **`admin-->controller-->module-->featured modules(any other)`**
goto to code

```
if ($product_info) {
                $this->data['products'][] = array(
                    'product_id' => $product_info['product_id'],
                    'name'       => $product_info['product_name']
                );
            }
```

replace it into your needs

```
if ($product_info) {
                $this->data['products'][] = array(
                    'product_id' => $product_info['product_id'],
                    'name'       => $product_info['model']
                );
            }
```

now you just need to refresh it. Product name will replace into model name in admin panel.

Comment: Hi @user1640432...thank you...for what can do for this?can you provide briefly please...Let me explain it...

Comment: Go to autocomplete function in admin->controller->catalog->product.php .. find $json[] = array(
 'product_id' => $result['product_id'],
 'name'       => html_entity_decode($result['name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'), 
 'model'      => $result['model'],
 'option'     => $option_data,
 'price'      => $result['price']
);
changed name to model in the second line like
html_entity_decode($result['model'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'),

Now in the search list you can see the product model number

Comment: Hi @user1640432...If you change that autocomplete function it will affect everything based on autocomplete so you just make about changes..It will change it individually..so you can follow any way to reach destination.Thnkx a lot for guide me

Comment: you can create your own function with different name by coping the existing one & call it from where you want to show model number instead of product name.

Answer (score 0):

```
'name' => strip_tags(html_entity_decode(
    $result['model'] . ' - ' . $result['name'],
    ENT_QUOTES,
    'UTF-8'
)),
```

gives model and name.